# RedirectAttribute's addFlashAttribute function not working as wanted

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

in the first 4 if statements when the condition in it is true , the addFlashAttribute adds an key and a string to the redirectAttributes object . but it doesnt in my case , because of this , the below line

```
String error = (String) inputFlashMap.get("passwordError");
```

gives an java.lang.NullPointerException.

the complete code:

```
        if(fName.length()==0){
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("fnameError","First name cant be empty");
            
        }if(lName.length()==0) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("lnameError","Last name cant be empty");
        }if(password.length()<=7) {
            
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("passwordError","Password cant be empty neither be less than 8 characters");
        }if(!matcher.matches()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("emailError","The Email entered is not accepted");
        }
        
        Map<String, ?> inputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
        
        System.out.println("Registration Form aint Right");
        
        //below lies the error
        String error = (String) inputFlashMap.get("passwordError");
        

        System.out.println(error);
```

i have checked myself if the 4 if conditions were working or not .it definitely does but the addFlashAttribute doesnt add the key and string associated to the key to the redirectAttributes object.due to which the null pointer exception occurs . why is this and how do i fix this ?

Comment: Probably your inputFlashMap is null?

Comment: @Sergey Vasnev oh ya i just tested  by printing out the line : RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request); seems this line is returning null any idea why this may be ? syntax seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Use : redirectAttributes.getFlashAttributes() instead of

```
RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
```